# Qt: singleton logging class get different instance accross plugins and thread

Tags: qt, thread-safety, singleton

I have spent hours trying to understand why my logger class does not work.
The idea is to hook existing *qDebug*, *qWarning* and *qFatal* to one of my slots and also extend the macro list with new ones (*qInfo* in this example)
I tried to follow the following guidelines:
[Using a Singleton Class across a Qt Application and its Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689370/using-a-singleton-class-across-a-qt-application-and-its-plugins)

```
#pragma once

#include <QtGui>
#include <QMutex>

//! Creates a fake call, to have a cleaner design.
extern void qInfo(const char* fmt);

#define QtTraceMsg  QtMsgType(6)
#define QtInfoMsg   QtMsgType(7)

class MsgHandler: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void newMsg(QtMsgType type, const QString &msg);

public:
    static MsgHandler *instance();
    static void Handler(QtMsgType type, const char *msg);

private:
    MsgHandler() { qRegisterMetaType<QtMsgType>("QtMsgType"); } // important
    static MsgHandler* _instance;
};
```

and cpp:

```
#include "MsgHandler.h"

MsgHandler* MsgHandler::_instance = NULL;

MsgHandler * MsgHandler::instance()
{
    static QMutex mutex;

    if (_instance == NULL)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        if (_instance == NULL)
            _instance = new MsgHandler;
        mutex.unlock();
    }

    return _instance;
}

void MsgHandler::Handler(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
    QString s = msg;
    emit instance()->newMsg(type, s);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void qInfo(const char *msg)
{
    MsgHandler::instance()->Handler(QtInfoMsg, msg);
}
```

then in the main I register my handler

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Handle error messages
    qInstallMsgHandler(MsgHandler::Handler);
}
```

Everything works perfectly in the main thread. But from a plugin that runs its own thread it fail:

```
void MyPlugin::run()
{
    qWarning("Test debug"); //works fine
    MsgHandler::instance()->Handler(QtInfoMsg, "info 2"); //creates a new instance!
    qInfo("test info"); //also creates a new instance!
}
```

Comment: In the question on your link @Naszta gives correct answer, but TS realization does not coincide with it. You should make separate _statically linked shared_ library, not _static library_. Static library will be linked 2 times both to your plug-in and app, but shared library will be loaded once.

Comment: Hum ok. And would you have any hint regarding how to make statically linked shared libraries. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Too late for edit: So I need to compile a dll and not a lib (I'm running windows) and then statically link this dll in both the main app and the plugins?

Comment: Exactly. It seems you only need to change `CONFIG` from `static` to `shared` in singleton project and correctly set `dllimpot/dllexport` attributes in header file.

Comment: I get this error when moc'ing:
**error C2491: 'MsgHandler::staticMetaObject' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed**
I think the problem is that my class inherit from QObject

Comment: It shouldn't. Qt itself is a set of shred libraries. Look, how it is made there. For example defenition of `QWidget`: `class Q_GUI_EXPORT QWidget` and `Q_GUI_EXPORT` macro does all the magic. It is set to `__declspec(dllexport)` while building GUI lib and to  `__declspec(dllimport)` otherwise. You should do smth like this. This is relevant for `Windows` only, of cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to pass a pointer to the MsgHandler to each plugin.