# How to Use Same Class Between Plugins and App in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I created a plugin in Qt. Plugin Class and App Class use a same class named ShareData. 
This is ShareData Class:

```
//sharedata.h
class ShareData
{
public:
    ShareData();
};

//sharedata.cpp
ShareData::ShareData()
{

}
```

But When I create an instance in plugin class as follows:

```
 //plugin.pro
INCLUDEPATH += $PWD/../echowindow/



 //echoplugin.h  
 #include "sharedata.h"
class EchoPlugin : public QObject, EchoInterface
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.Examples.EchoInterface" FILE "echoplugin.json")
        Q_INTERFACES(EchoInterface)

    public:
        EchoPlugin();
        ShareData* sharedata;
    };

//echoplugin.cpp
EchoPlugin::EchoPlugin()
{
    sharedata = new ShareData();
}
```

Then I run the project and I got an error :

```
error: undefined reference to `ShareData::ShareData()'
```

Add this is my class structure:

```
-echoplugin
    -echoplugin.pro
    -echopluginwindow
        -echowindow.pro
        -Headers
            -echointerface.h
            -echowindow.h
            -sharedata.h
        -Sources
             -echowindow.cpp
             -main.cpp
             -sharedata.cpp

    -Plugin
        -plugin.pro
        -Headers
            -echoplugin.h
        -Sources
            -echoplugin.cpp
```

What should I do then I can use ShareData Class in Plugin EchoPlugin Class?

Comment: Do you compile `sharedata.cpp` and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin should be independent of main application, so you cannot use classes defined in it. Your build error is probably beacuse of shareddata.cpp is not compiled during plugin build.

If you really want use such design I would suggest creation of library for `SharedData`.

`INCLUDEPATH` only says that you can use headers of shareddata. The problem occurs on the linking stage.

Comment: Thank you very much. And I have another question: Is there any other ways can replace this design except create a library of ShareData?

Comment: @Firers The problem is that your plugin code use `new SharedData`. To use it it must have access to SharedData constructor. You can "give" it with adding to `SOURCES` and `HEADERS` shareddata.cpp and shareddata.h (with manual path), but you can get linking error of whole application.

Comment: Thank you very much. I add sharedata.h and sharedata.cpp to Plugin and it worked. But I have another question. I modify the ShareData Class to a  Singleton Pattern Class. I use ShateData Class in App and Plugin twice, and I print something in ShareData's constructor. The console shows me that it print twice. How to use Singleton Pattern Class between App and Plugin? Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: @FIrers Showing your implementation would be helpful here. The first thing is, that you should write `SharedData *GetInstance()` function. Constructor should be called only in your main appliaction, plugin should only get pointer to instance when it's need it - not allocate it. It is possible, that when you use this pattern, adding shareddata.cpp to plugin build will not be needed.

Comment: In comment show my code block is not convenience. I paste my code in next anwser. Can you help  me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I found an answer at the page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689370/using-a-singleton-class-across-a-qt-application-and-its-plugins). Make the class to the shared library is worked. Thank you very much.